# Capture logs on DataDog agent from a Java application running on a Docker container

Tags: java, docker, datadog

I have an Java application running on a container in the same VM that my DataDog agent is running, the agent, with a very basic and general configuration, is capture all logs and send them to Datadog site.

The issue is that they are being sent to DataDog it seems that the source is the docker image name and it causes the logs not being matched to a pipeline.

So, two questions regarding this:

1 - Considering that this is a Java application on a Docker container, should the source be Java or Docker? If I pick Java some system logs will not be parsed correctly e.g. docker or OpenJDK initialization. If I pick Docker, then my application logs will not be correct. What is the recommended approach?

2 - Where is the best place to configure the source? I was trying to find examples of this on the agent configuration file, but I can only find examples of log processing rules using FILE (and they are very basic).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how are you running your docker container ? 

i would recommend containerizing a datadog agent and linking it to your java container, with something like a docker-compose file, and configuring datadog in java mode

Comment: If Datadog is in Java mode, how to deal with the outputs that are not Java, like docker or system logs? (Agent is running as a service o VM right now)